# Need help in deciding the type of function and their range and inverse for the functions $p,q,r$ and $s$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $p,q,r$ and $s$ be the following functions

$p: R\to R$ defined by $P(x) = (1/2)x + 1$. $R$ represents set of all real numbers.

$q:Z \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $q(x) = \{ 1,$ if $x \geq 1; 0,$ if $\leq 0 \}$

$r: R\setminus {0} \to R$ defined by $r(x) = 6/x$

$s: Z \to R$ defined by $s(x) = 3x + 1/2$

(a) What are the ranges of $p,q,r$ and $s$? Which of them are onto?

(b) Which of $p,q,r$ and $s$ are one to one? Explain?

(c) State whether $p$ and $q$ have inverse functions and, if they do, give a formula for the function and give its domain, codomain and range?

For part (a) For function $p$ the range is $\{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5\}$. For every whole number starting form $0$ the range keeps on increasing by $0.5$. But is it correct with a function involving real numbers? I think it's an onto function.

For a function like $q$ how do I define the range? Is it onto?

For $r$ the first few values are $\{6,3,2,1.5,1.2,1....\}$ I don't think it is a correct way of showing the range. What would be the correct answer? This is probably not onto as there is no $0$ in $R\setminus {0}$ but there is in $R$.

For $s$ the range is $\{-5.5, -2.5, 0.5, 3.5, 6.5, 9.5\}$. I think is an onto function as well.

For part (b) I think $p,q $ and $s$ are onto functions. But I do not know how to explain them. I am not sure about $q$ though. Any help would be great here.

For part (c) $p$ has an inverse function. It is $p(y) = (y - 1/2)/3$. It's domain is $R$ and codomain is $R$ and range is $\{-5/6, -1/2, -1/6, 1/6, 1/2....\}$. For $q$ I do not understand if it has an inverse function. Does it?

Sorry for the lengthy question, I have indicated where I need help in. If anyone is interested to help me out It would benefit me greatly.

Comment: Actually, for the function $p$, the range is the entire codomain $\Bbb R$ since $\forall~y\in\Bbb R~\exists~x=2(y-1)\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$. So, every element of $\Bbb R$ has a pre-image under $p$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: For $q$, the range is $\{0,1\}$ since both of them have pre-images under $q$ in $\Bbb Z$ (infact there are many pre-images which is why the map $q$ is not one-one but it's onto).

Comment: For $r$, the range is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ since there's no pre-image of $0\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ under $r$ in $\Bbb R$ and for all $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, there exists $x=\frac 6y$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: For $s$, the range will be a countable subset of $\Bbb R$, namely the set $\{3x+1/2\mid x\in\Bbb Z\}$, so it's not onto but it's one-one.

Comment: @learner  You should turn your comments into an answer.